# typescript - object destructuring in find function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is an error when I want to destructuring the object:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ItemType | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";

type ItemType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};
export default function App() {
  const items: Array<ItemType> = [
    { id: 1, name: "Name 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Name 2" }
  ];
  let { name } = items.find((item: ItemType) => {
    return item.id === 1;
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-wpwtdx?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: what happens if `find` doesn't find anything? (is what TypeScript is trying to warn you about)

Comment: @apokryfos so how should I handle it

Comment: It depends. If you know for certain that `find` will never fail you can do `items.find(...)!` to say that it's never going to be undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot destruct something when it's potentially `null|undefined`.

You need to make sure it is not `null|undefined` then destructing would work.

```js
type ItemType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

function App() {
  const items: Array<ItemType> = [
    { id: 1, name: "Name 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Name 2" }
  ];
  const item = items.find(item => item.id === 1);
  if(item){
    const {name} = item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just get your object using `find` function:

`let item = items.find(item => item.id === 1);`

Then check if `item` is null or undefined. If it isn't, you can access its name by `item.name`:

`let name = item && item.name`

**Code below**

```
import "./styles.css";

type ItemType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};
export default function App() {
  const items: Array<ItemType> = [
    { id: 1, name: "Name 1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Name 2" }
  ];
  let item = items.find(item => item.id === 1);
  let name = item && item.name;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to destructure object which can be `undefined`, however, you can get value using `obj?.propertyname` or `obj?.array?.[0]?.propertyname`.

And yes using `array.find()` for finding element in array is definitely going to be return `undefined` as `array.find()` returns found object or undefined.

But if you are very sure that you will always find an object from an array then in typescript you should use `array.find()!` in this way obviously it's not recommended as best practices you can then overcome your issue by not using destructuring on `array.find()`